# Mapping List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> to custom object in C#

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I have a method that returns `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>`. These are column data from different tables in a database depending of the parameters of the call and I would like map then to custom objects depending on the table data returned.

As an example is the return list contain data from table 1 with column , `(C1, C2, C3, C4)`

The possible returned values are

```
KeyValPair<C1, ValueOfC1>
KeyValPair<C2, ValueofC2>
etc....
```

This list should be mapped to a list of CustomC1 where CustomC1 is defined as follow:

```
public class CustumC1 { int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4 }
```

I need to transform the `list` of the `KeyValuePair` to the `List` of `CustomC1`.

So I currently have a method definition which is

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> MyMethod(int param)
```

and I want

```
List<TResult> MyMethod<TResult> (int param)
```

below is my original method that needs to be changed to return a supplied object:

```
 private async Task<List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>> GetData(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
            string sql = CustomQueryString;
            List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> result = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
            var reader = await new SqlCommand(sql, conn).ExecuteReaderAsync();

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                columnNames.Add(reader.GetName(i));
            }

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> resultRecord = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            resultRecord.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key: columnName, value: reader[columnName].ToString()));
        }
        result.Add(resultRecord);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please, show what have you tried so far. Example data will also be useful for solving your question

Comment: Yeah you can do this, however something tells me that you should probably just be using an ORM, or dapper or something

Comment: More info added. Please see the method that need to be changed to return TResult instead of List<List<KeyValPair

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to read from the database? And how do you map to a `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` ?, As far as I understand you are mapping  to a keyValuePair to later map it to a generic object. I do not think this is a good approach as you are opening yourself to a lot more complexity with scalability and errors. Better to have a concrete method that return a concret object from the database, as mention in the comments using dapper would be a good solution. Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
    var modelProperties = modelType.GetProperties();// modelType is your generic object type
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType); 

foreach (var property in modelProperties)
{
  var propertyInfo = instance.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
  var propertyValue = yourList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Key==property.Name);
  propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, ChangeType(propertyValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);       
}
```

UPDATE

For example this code is clear and expressive and tells me what the other developer is doing and I can understand the context of it, it is using Dapper to query and made in CQRS principles:

```
 public class GetHousesHandler : IRequestHandler<GetHouses, IEnumerable<House>>
    {
        private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

        public GetHousesHandler(IDbConnection connection)
        {
            _connection = connection ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connection));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<House>> Handle(GetHouses request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var sql = $@"
                SELECT StreetName AS {nameof(House.StreetName)}
                  , Number AS {nameof(House.Number)}
                FROM dbo.HouseView
                WHERE Number = @Number;";

            var param = new
            {
                request.Number,
            };

            return await _connection.QueryAsync<House>(
                sql: sql,
                param: param
                );
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is something you would try to avoid in a typed language. How much speed are you gaining for the price of having runtime errors?

Comment: Please check the new info. I have provided the method that need to be changed

Comment: I suggest to refactor your code complete to make it more expressive and clear to read. If it is generic it does not give other developer any idea of what data are you getting `GetData` makes me want to ask what data? It is better to have a concrete object which you can have in your method signature which will clearly indicate what are you getting. Divide and conquer. Try to use dapper which will allow you to do the same think with more expression and clearness in your code. There is nothing wrong in having multiple queries which return different type of objects. I will give you an example.